# Create a column of classifications based on the contents of a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given the following data

```py
random.seed(1)
import pandas as pd
import random
starts = ['a. ', 'bc. ', '']
v = pd.Series( [f"{s}foo{i}" for i,s in enumerate([
    random.choice(starts) for _ in range(5)])])
```

which looks like

```py
In [284]: v
Out[284]:
0     a. foo0
1        foo1
2     a. foo2
3    bc. foo3
4     a. foo4
dtype: object
```

I would like to create a column which classifies `v` based on its prefix,
which would be as follows:

```
original col       classification

 a. foo0      ->   type_a
    foo1      ->   neither
 a. foo2      ->   type_a
bc. foo3      ->   type_bc
 a. foo4      ->   type_a
```

The solution should apply to a dataframe, the following for example

```py
random.seed(1)
import pandas as pd
import random
starts = ['a. ', 'bc. ', '']
df = pd.DataFrame( {
    'A' : [f"{s}foo{i}" for i,s in enumerate([
        random.choice(starts) for _ in range(5)])],
    'B' : [random.randint(10,20) for _ in range(5)] })
```

Could be processed as:

```
In [292]: df
Out[292]:
          A   B  class
0   a. foo0  17  type_one
1      foo1  17  neither
2   a. foo2  17  type_one
3  bc. foo3  20  type_two
4   a. foo4  16  type_one
```

## edit

This approach is nice :

```py
('type_' + v.str.extract(r'^([^\.]+)\.')).fillna('neither')
# also 
v.str.extract(r'^([^\.]+)\.').radd('type_').fillna('neither')
```

But it depends on the values in the current data, I would like for the solution to be independent of the current values, for example; the solution might be in the form

```
In [292]: df
Out[292]:
          A   B  class
0   a. foo0  17  type_one
1      foo1  17  neither
2   a. foo2  17  type_one
3  bc. foo3  20  type_two
4   a. foo4  16  type_one
```

Comment: `v.str.extract(r'^([^\.]+)\.').radd('type_').fillna('neither')`

Comment: @user3483203 thank you, please see the edit though.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Comment: @AMC have you automated this response? Have a look at the post, the issues pretty well explained. Or, be specific about what you feel lacks clarity, currently your input has no value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to mask the dataframe and set values according to the mask.

Using the following data as in the original post:

```py
# sys.version
# '3.7.6 (default, Dec 30 2019, 19:38:28) \n[Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.16)]'
import pandas as pd
import random
random.seed(1)

starts = ['a. ', 'bc. ', '']
df = pd.DataFrame( {
    'A' : [f"{s}foo{i}" for i,s in enumerate([random.choice(starts) for _ in range(5)])],
    'B' : [random.randint(10,20) for _ in range(5)] })
```

Replacements could be carried out as follows:

```py
df.loc[df['A'].str.startswith("a."), "class"] = "type_a"
df.loc[df['A'].str.startswith("bc."), "class"] = "type_bc"
df.loc[:, 'class'].fillna("neither", inplace=True)
```

A cleaner approach might be to store prefixes and corresponding "types" in a
mapping, then modify the dataframe according to it:

```py
# df is the same data as originally created
mapping = {
    "a.": "type_a",
    "bc.": "type_bc",
}
for k, v in mapping.items():
    mask = df["A"].str.startswith(k)
    df.loc[mask, "class"] = v
df["class"].fillna("neither", inplace=True)
```

Comment: thanks, using `for` loops with pandas often makes me feel as though I'm doing something wrong, but perhaps in this case there's no alternative. A downside to this approach might be that if there were many prefixes to catch using a mapping might become cumbersome, but given the classes are stated anyway there might not be an alternative. Initially I assumed I was missing something in Pandas, but not I'm not sure.

Comment: `for` loops are not always a bad thing, but it's good intuition to question the use of `for` loops in pandas (and numpy). it would be bad practice, for example, to loop through each row. a vectorized approach would be preferred in that case.

Comment: You can use `df['A']` to get column `'A'`, it's a bit more compact than `df.loc[:, 'A']`.

Answer (score 1):

This works with the example you provided, although there is definitely a risk that it relies on properties which the actual data does not have. Let me know! :)

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df_data = {'A': {0: 'a. foo0', 1: 'foo1', 2: 'a. foo2', 3: 'bc. foo3', 4: 'a. foo4'},
           'B': {0: 17, 1: 17, 2: 17, 3: 20, 4: 16}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=df_data)

print(df)

type_map = {'a.': 'type_one', 'bc.': 'type_two', np.NaN: 'type_neither'}
df['A_type'] = df['A'].str.extract(r"^(\S+\.)\s", expand=False).map(type_map)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
          A   B
0   a. foo0  17
1      foo1  17
2   a. foo2  17
3  bc. foo3  20
4   a. foo4  16
          A   B        A_type
0   a. foo0  17      type_one
1      foo1  17  type_neither
2   a. foo2  17      type_one
3  bc. foo3  20      type_two
4   a. foo4  16      type_one
```

Comment: is the `.` necessary in `(\S+.)` ? Or is `\.` intended (which would make sense, just checking). Or perhaps you're accounting for other chars after non space? I'm not too sure

Comment: @baxx It’s meant to be both, fixed!